# no such file to load -- rest_client

Tags: ruby, cloud-foundry, rest-client

I use ruby in Cloud Foundry.but recently got a error in a

```
file(plugin.rb,this is a framework I added to Cloud foundry v1):
in `require': no such file to load -- rest_client (LoadError)
```

I use "gem" in Ubuntu. "gem list" shows I really have rest-client1.6.7.And I have reinstalled rest-client.

```
"ruby -v": ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]
"gem env | grep 'RUBY EXECUTABLE'":  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

In the folder `/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies` I have 3 versions ruby (installed by cloud foundry, not by me):

```
"ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1"
"ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1"
"ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/gems/1.8".
```

They all have "rest-client-1.6.7" under their folder.

I do not have "Gemfile" in this,because "plugin.rb" is called by
cloudfoundry itself. And I make a test.rb in the same folder,run it
myself and it works fine,no error with"require 'rest_client' "
maybe cloudfoundry use 1.9.2/1.9.3 itself?

I'm confused about ruby file structure, how to solve that problem?

thanks for help.